# How can I recognize Anti-items in a 7zip archive?

Tags: 7zip, sharpcompress

I'm using SharpCompress to unzip a 7zip archive. The `IArchive` created by `ArchiveFactory.Open` returns an `IEnumerable<IArchiveEntry>`, but `IArchiveEntry` contains nothing indicating if an entry is an anti-item.

Is there a way to recognize anti-items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the project's issue tracker.

http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/workitem/33